# Do Android Vanilla updates come straight from Google?

Tags: android, updates

Usually Android updates are distributed to devices by device manufacturers since they need to adjust the patches they get from Google to their tweaked interfaces/drivers.

Is it same with Android "Vanilla" OS or do the devices with those versions get updates straight from Google servers without manufacturer's interference?

Let's say my phone's manufacturer goes bankrupt. Will I still get automatic updates to my Vanilla Android 5.1? Or even OS upgrades (5 -> 6)? Or is the device doomed to be outdated from then on?

Comment: Assuming you can root your device, you're welcome to install custom ROM and find XDA developers forum section for your device

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a "google phone", nexus or pixel, then you can get the OTA update from Google.  Otherwise the update will come from the manufacturer to the carrier and then to you.  Are you using a non-google phone with Vanilla Android?  If so, did you install the OS on your own?

Comment: Actually I was about to buy a non-google phone with Vanilla Android from a bankrupt manufacturer. So I guess it will require some manual updating and I will not be able to enjoy the "flavor", so to speak. :)